# Как анимировать слайд меню swift

Tags: ios, swift, анимация, sliding-menu

Сделал кастомный слайд меню. Теперь проблема с анимацией закрытия меню.
По идее он должен выходит слева направо и заходить обратно. И не все элементы потом уходят с экрана, как их убрать вместе с `view`?
[Вот видео](https://youtu.be/x9oTePLuBFs)

Вот код

```
import UIKit

public extension UIDevice {

var modelName: String {
var systemInfo = utsname()
uname(&systemInfo)
let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
let identifier = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
    guard let value = element.value as? Int8 where value != 0 else { return identifier }
    return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
}

switch identifier {
case "iPhone4,1":                               return "iPhone 4s"
case "iPhone5,1", "iPhone5,2":                  return "iPhone 5"
case "iPhone5,3", "iPhone5,4":                  return "iPhone 5c"
case "iPhone6,1", "iPhone6,2":                  return "iPhone 5s"
case "iPhone7,2":                               return "iPhone 6"
case "iPhone7,1":                               return "iPhone 6 Plus"
case "iPhone8,1":                               return "iPhone 6s"
case "iPhone8,2":                               return "iPhone 6s Plus"
case "iPhone9,1", "iPhone9,3":                  return "iPhone 7"
case "iPhone9,2", "iPhone9,4":                  return "iPhone 7 Plus"
case "iPhone8,4":                               return "iPhone SE"
case "iPad2,1", "iPad2,2", "iPad2,3", "iPad2,4":return "iPad 2"
case "iPad3,1", "iPad3,2", "iPad3,3":           return "iPad 3"
case "iPad3,4", "iPad3,5", "iPad3,6":           return "iPad 4"
case "iPad4,1", "iPad4,2", "iPad4,3":           return "iPad Air"
case "iPad5,3", "iPad5,4":                      return "iPad Air 2"
case "iPad2,5", "iPad2,6", "iPad2,7":           return "iPad Mini"
case "iPad4,4", "iPad4,5", "iPad4,6":           return "iPad Mini 2"
case "iPad4,7", "iPad4,8", "iPad4,9":           return "iPad Mini 3"
case "iPad5,1", "iPad5,2":                      return "iPad Mini 4"
case "iPad6,3", "iPad6,4", "iPad6,7", "iPad6,8":return "iPad Pro"
case "i386", "x86_64":                          return "Simulator"
default:                                        return identifier
}
}
}

let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds


class LeftMenu: UIViewController {

var menuIsActive = false
let x: CGFloat = 5
let y: CGFloat = 60
let height: CGFloat = 70
let width: CGFloat = 350

let size1_X: CGFloat = 5
let size1_Y: CGFloat = 70
let height1: CGFloat = 70
let width1: CGFloat = 350

let size2_X: CGFloat = 5
let size2_Y: CGFloat = 70
let height2: CGFloat = 70
let width2: CGFloat = 350

let size3_X: CGFloat = 5
let size3_Y: CGFloat = 70
let height3: CGFloat = 70
let width3: CGFloat = 350


let myView: UIView = {

let view = UIView()
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

return view
}()


func toggleMenu() {

let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "bgmenu")
let backgroundImageView = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)

let userImageView = UIImageView()
userImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
userImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 30
userImageView.clipsToBounds = true
userImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2
userImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 255.0 / 255, green: 215.0 / 255, blue: 0 / 255, alpha: 1).CGColor

let label = UILabel()
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.text = "КІРУ / ТІРКЕЛУ"
label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18)
label.userInteractionEnabled = true


let mainLogo = UIImage(named: "homegray@1x-1")
let mainImageView = UIImageView(image: mainLogo)
mainImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

let mainLabel = UILabel()
mainLabel.numberOfLines = 0
mainLabel.text = "БАСТЫ"
mainLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
mainLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18)

let contentLogo = UIImage(named: "menugray@1x-1")
let contentImageView = UIImageView(image: contentLogo)
contentImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

let contentLabel = UILabel()
contentLabel.numberOfLines = 0
contentLabel.text = "МАЗМҰНЫ"
contentLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
contentLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18)

let favoriteLogo = UIImage(named: "favgray@1x-1")
let favoriteImageView = UIImageView(image: favoriteLogo)
favoriteImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

let favoriteLabel = UILabel()
favoriteLabel.numberOfLines = 0
favoriteLabel.text = "ТАҢДАУЛЫЛАР"
favoriteLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
favoriteLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18)

let offlineLabel = UILabel()
offlineLabel.numberOfLines = 0
offlineLabel.text = "ОФФЛАЙН (~2 ГБ)"
offlineLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

let switcher = UISwitch()

switch UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName  {

case "iPhone 6 Plus", "iPhone 6s Plus", "iPhone 7 Plus":

    backgroundImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 70, width: 300, height: 100)

    userImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 90, width: 60, height: 60)

    label.frame = CGRect(x: 97, y: 105, width: 135, height: 30)

    mainImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 190, width: 27, height: 27)
    mainLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 95, y: 193, width: 135, height: 30)

    contentImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 230, width: 27, height: 27)
    contentLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 95, y: 233, width: 135, height: 30)

    favoriteImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 51, y: 270, width: 27, height: 27)
    favoriteLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 95, y: 273, width: 140, height: 30)

    offlineLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 480, width: 180, height: 30)
    offlineLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20)

    switcher.frame = CGRect(x: 230, y: 480, width: 20, height: 20)
    print("Here 0")

//Ставим "Simulator" для того чтобы тесировать на Симуляторе
case "iPhone 6", "iPhone 6s", "iPhone 7", "Simulator":

    backgroundImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 350, height: 100)

    userImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 25, width: 60, height: 60)

    label.frame = CGRect(x: 97, y: 35, width: 135, height: 30)

    mainImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 190, width: 27, height: 27)
    mainLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 95, y: 193, width: 135, height: 30)

    contentImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 230, width: 27, height: 27)
    contentLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 95, y: 233, width: 135, height: 30)

    favoriteImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 51, y: 270, width: 27, height: 27)
    favoriteLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 95, y: 273, width: 140, height: 30)

    offlineLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 480, width: 180, height: 30)
    offlineLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20)

    switcher.frame = CGRect(x: 230, y: 480, width: 20, height: 20)
    print("Here 1")

case "iPhone 5", "iPhone 5c", "iPhone SE", "iPhone 5s":

    backgroundImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 100)

    userImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 20, width: 60, height: 60)

    label.frame = CGRect(x: 97, y: 32, width: 135, height: 30)

    mainImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 120, width: 27, height: 27)
    mainLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 95, y: 123, width: 135, height: 30)

    contentImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 160, width: 27, height: 27)
    contentLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 95, y: 163, width: 135, height: 30)

    favoriteImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 51, y: 200, width: 27, height: 27)
    favoriteLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 95, y: 203, width: 140, height: 30)

    offlineLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 410, width: 180, height: 30)
    offlineLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20)

    switcher.frame = CGRect(x: 230, y: 410, width: 20, height: 20)
    print("Here 2")
default: break

}


menuIsActive = !menuIsActive

if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow {

    if menuIsActive {

        window.addSubview(myView)

        //myView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 350, height: window.frame.height - height)

        myView.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
        backgroundImageView.addSubview(userImageView)
        backgroundImageView.addSubview(label)
        myView.addSubview(mainImageView)
        myView.addSubview(mainLabel)
        myView.addSubview(contentImageView)
        myView.addSubview(contentLabel)
        myView.addSubview(favoriteImageView)
        myView.addSubview(favoriteLabel)
        myView.addSubview(offlineLabel)
        myView.addSubview(switcher)


        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0, options: .TransitionFlipFromLeft, animations: {

            switch UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName  {

            case "iPhone 6 Plus", "iPhone 6s Plus", "iPhone 7 Plus":
                self.myView.frame = CGRect(x: self.size3_X, y: self.size3_Y, width: 350, height: window.frame.height - self.height)
                print("Here 0")

            case "iPhone 6", "iPhone 6s", "iPhone 7", "Simulator":
                self.myView.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 80, width: 350, height: 550)
                backgroundImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 350, height: 100)
                print("Here 1")

            case "iPhone 5", "iPhone 5c", "iPhone SE", "iPhone 5s":
                self.myView.frame = CGRect(x: self.size1_X, y: self.size1_Y, width: 300, height: 450)
                backgroundImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 100)
                print("Here 2")
            default: break

            }
            }, completion: nil)

    } else {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {

            print("Left Menu close")

            self.myView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

            backgroundImageView.center.x  -= window.bounds.width

            }, completion: nil)
            //{ finished in self.myView.removeFromSuperview() }
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: если нужна хорошая менюшка то - SWRevealViewController; https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы хотите чтоб он "выезжал" слева, Вам нужно менять только `origin x` у вьюшки.

Навскидку для Вашего случая:

```
//Начальное положение вьюшки. Положение х за границами видимости на ширину вьюшки.
myView.frame = CGRect(x: -350, y: y, width: 350, height: window.frame.height - height)
...
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0, options: .TransitionFlipFromLeft, animations: {
    //т.е. она только движется по х. С -ширины до 0. и так же заезжает, с 0 до -ширины. Высота и ширина должна быть неизменной.
    self.myView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: 350, height: window.frame.height - height)
    //а так как она у Вас только выезжает сбоку, вообще логично менять только x:
    //self?.vLeft.frame.origin.x = 0    //выезжает
    //self?.vLeft.frame.origin.x = -350 //заезжает
    }
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо большое!